# Inserting data into H2 database through java

Tags: java, database, h2

The data does not insert into the database as should. I believe that I have made the proper connnection as stated in the documentation. Can someone please help me to improve my code?

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class DB_Connection {

    private final String jdbcdriver = "org.h2.Driver";
    private final String db_url = "jdbc:h2:~/RetailerDB";
    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    private Connection Connect() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(jdbcdriver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,"","");
            return conn;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param emp_id
     * @param username
     * @param first_name
     * @param last_name
     * @param password
     * @param position
     */
    public void Register(String emp_id, String username, String first_name, String last_name,String password, String position){
        try {
            conn = Connect();
            String sql = "INSERT into EMPLOYEES values(?,?,?,?,?,?,);";
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really think you need to have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Look at `Register` method - no values that you pass in are used

Comment: what exactly is the issue? "Doesn't work" isn't enough

Comment: see this [link](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement)

Comment: you are missing the calls to `setXXXX()` to provide the values for each `?`. And it should be `conn.prepareStatement(sql)` (not `createStatement)`